# If $R$ is an integral domain then $R[x]$ forms an integral domain

Tags: proof-verification, polynomials, ring-theory

> **Theorem**: Let $R$ be an integral domain, then ring of polynomials $R[x]$ form an integral domain.

To prove this, i first prove a little lemma (not giving the proof here):

> **Lemma**: Let $R$ be integral domain, then $\forall p,q\in R[x]$ we have that $\deg{(pq)}=\deg{(p)}+\deg{(q)}$.

In order to prove the theorem, we have to show that if we have any two nonzero polynomials $p,q$, then their product is nonzero. Because $p,q$ is nonzero, we have that their degree is greater or equal to 0. By lemma $\deg{(pq)}=\deg{(p)}+\deg{(q)}\geq0+0=0$ this shows that $\deg{(pq)}\geq 0$ so $pq$ is nonzero and we conclude that $R[x]$ forms an integral domain.

Is my proof valid or should I aim for something stronger? All the proofs I am aware of always are long examining the terms of the polynomial $pq$ by definition and so on, so I was just wondering, if this argument is correct. Thanks

Comment: The lemma requires $R$ to be an integral domain. It can be proved by simply comparing leading terms. They cannot cancel. Consider the zero polynomial separately.

Comment: Having $deg(pq) \geq 0$ could mean $deg(pq)=0$ and does not imply $pq \neq 0$, as degree of zero polynomial is zero

Comment: @nikola well, usually the degree of zero polynomial is defined as $-\infty$ or $-1$. Yes, i forgot to add in the lemma, that we assume $R$ is an integral domain, editing it.

Comment: zero polynomial is just another constant, and degree of any constant is zero, making degree of polynomial lower then zero is pointless

Comment: How are  $p,q$ related with $f,g$?

Comment: @nikola, the point of defining $\mathrm{deg}(0) = -\infty$ is so that for integral domains you have the rule $\mathrm{deg}(fg) = \mathrm{deg}(f) + \mathrm{deg}(g)$.

Comment: Oh, just took other letters, $f,g$ are meant to be the $p,q$ im talking about, corrected it now

Comment: Zero polynomial cannot have negative infinite degree... As your would never have been true...

Comment: Yeah, in fact if i defined $\deg(0)=0$ then take $f=0$ and $g$ with degree $n\geq 1$ then $\deg(fg)=\deg(0\cdot g)=\deg(0)\neq \deg(f)+\deg(g)=0+n$ That's the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my proof valid or should I aim for something stronger?

Your proof is perfectly valid.

> All the proofs I am aware of always are long examining the terms of the polynomial $pq$ by definition and so on, so I was just wondering, if this argument is correct.

I doubt the proofs are *that much longer*; all the work that goes into examining coefficients of $pq$ will instead go into proving the lemma.

Comment: Yeah, that's true, the part with examining the coefficients is in the lemma, thanks for the verification!